# Dynamic Spinner not working correctly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-spinner

I have a spinner2 which will have day and month, when user select day, s1 and s2 will display hours and mins respectively.

On startup of the activity, I have the daily selected.
The problem is I keep on getting toast of daily. Which suggested that it gets selecteditem endlessly. Also, I cant select values in s1 and s2, the spinner keep on refreshing among themselves. How to solve this?

```
public class try_spinner extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
Spinner spinner1, spinner2, s1, s2, s3;
String app_name, room_name;
TextView app, room;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.try_spinner);

DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

int width = dm.widthPixels;
int height = dm.heightPixels;

getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * .9), (int) (height * .7));

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
final String app_string = extras.getString("APPLIANCE_NAME");
final String room_string = extras.getString("APPLIANCE_ROOM");

app = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.app_name);
app.setText(app_string);
room = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.room_name);
room.setText(room_string);

spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.s1);
s2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.s2);
s3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.s3);
spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
s3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

if (app_string.equals("Lighting")) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.lighting));
    dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
    spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
} else if (app_string.equals("Shower Heater")) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.shower_heater));
    dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
    spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
} else {
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.empty));
    dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
    spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
}

}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                       long arg3) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
String txt_spinner2 = String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem());
Toast.makeText(this, txt_spinner2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
if (txt_spinner2.contentEquals("Daily")) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.days));
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    s1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    String txt_s1 = String.valueOf(s1.getSelectedItem());

    //set for daily hours usage
    List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hours));
    dataAdapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    dataAdapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();
    s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter3);

    //set for daily minutes usage
    List<String> list4 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter4 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hours));
    dataAdapter4.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    dataAdapter4.notifyDataSetChanged();
    s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter4);

    //set for daily empty thrd space
    List<String> list5 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter5 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.empty));
    dataAdapter5.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    dataAdapter5.notifyDataSetChanged();
    s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter5);
}

else if (txt_spinner2.contentEquals("Monthly")) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Conveyance");//you should add items from db here(2nd spinner)
    list.add("the end");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter6 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter6.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    dataAdapter6.notifyDataSetChanged();
    s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter6);
}

}
```

Comment: What I get from your code is that you are supplying values to `spinner1` but when clicked, you are taking item from `spinner2`. Why is that?

Comment: both spinner1 and spinner2 have values set initially, while s1,s2,s3 are empty initially. 
spinner1 will be set according to what are the text inside a textview title, such as heater or lighting. spinner2 is the dynamic one where user select daily or monthly, then s1,s2,s3 will be set into values of (hours, mins, null) for daily or (days,hours,mins) for monthly.. the problem is with dynamic spinner2 causes s1,s2,s3 to become unable to select. they keep on refreshing the spinners s1,s2,s3, proved by getting numerous toast of ("daily"), which is right after the `(spinner2.getSelectedItem());
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all set adapter first to spinner and then call setOnItemSelectedListener() for it. b'z when spinner value gets initialized it even call setOnItemSelectedListener method. you can put debugger and check.

Secondly always check for which spinner or widget you are getting event, in your case for spinner you can do like this

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                               long id) {

    Spinner clickedSpinner = (Spinner) parent;

    switch (clickedSpinner.getId()) {
        case R.id.spinner1:
            // your code for spinner1
            String str = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            break;
    }
}
```

so change your code and see its working or not. hope it will help you...

Comment: `Spinner clickedSpinner = (Spinner) parent;` does this line means setting which spinner as the parent that will decide the values of child under them?

Comment: @whoami no that is casting view to spinner. Adapterview is like abstract parent class so you can cast into specific child class. in this case casting into spinner.

Comment: i think it worked now. one more question. if i have a button that when clicked, it will get the values of the spinners. how can i access the values in the itemselected class?

Comment: @whoami well than accept that answer and for you 2nd question you can do like this in case String str = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString(); 
you can take variable local or class variable and then access it when user click on button.